# Create column displaying the term from the term set

Tags: 2013, column, term

I would like to create a column for a document library that shows the term that a document has been tagged with from the Term Set from the managed metadata store.  Is this possible?

Comment: How the document is getting tagged? While uploading?

Comment: Yes. Tagged when added to the library.